# How to abort pending query requests?

Tags: query, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-task

Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.24 I have a map which is configured to query a layer each time the map extent changes. This means that multiple sequential requests are sent if the map is moved quickly:

[image]

My goal is to cancel any pending queries, before sending the next query.

[FeatureLayer.queryFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#queryFeatures) lists `options.signal` but I can't figure out how to implement this. Following the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal I added:

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;
controller.abort();
```

but I don't know at which point I should call `controller.abort()`. If I include this in conjunction with `layer.queryFeatures(query, { signal })` all queries are aborted.

I tried adding a button to call `controller.abort` but once this is called, all further requests immediately abort.

**How can I abort any pending queries, but allow future queries to execute?**

Demo code at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/oNdPqKN - see the queries in the developer tools Network tab.

Comment: I would do it the other way and query the data only if the map is steady for a certain time.

Comment: @BerndLoigge that's a great idea, thanks. However, some of these queries take up to a minute as I'm querying complex polygons, so I'd still like to find the ability to cancel pending queries. I thought about freezing the map until the queries are all complete but that UX is not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `AbortController` and reference its Signal `signal: controller.signal` in the `options` object in the [`queryFeatures`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#queryFeatures) method (second parameter). Then you can abort the query using the `controller.abort()` method.

**Update:**
You need to create a new instance of the `AbortController` after your query was aborted and reference a new signal so that a new query can work.

See this working [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhadzLxo/1/).

For testing you could throttle your network and click the `Abort` button.

```js
// Create reference to AbortController
let controller = null;


  function queryFeatures(screenPoint) {
    const point = view.toMap(screenPoint);
    controller = new AbortController();
    layer.queryFeatures({
      geometry: point,
      // distance and units will be null if basic query selected
      distance: distance,
      units: units,
      spatialRelationship: "intersects",
      returnGeometry: false,
      returnQueryGeometry: true,
      outFields: ["*"],
    },
      {
        signal: controller.signal // Reference signal
      }).then((featureSet) => {
        // set graphic location to mouse pointer and add to mapview
        pointGraphic.geometry = point;
        view.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
        // open popup of query result
        view.popup.open({
          location: point,
          features: featureSet.features,
          featureMenuOpen: true
        });
        if (featureSet.queryGeometry) {
          bufferGraphic.geometry = featureSet.queryGeometry;
          view.graphics.add(bufferGraphic);
        }
      });
  }

window.abortQuery = function () {
  console.log("aborting");
  controller.abort();
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer so it works again after the query was aborted

Comment: Many thanks for the tips. This was the solution: _You need to create a new instance of the AbortController after your query was aborted_. I updated the demo at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/oNdPqKN to include your suggestion - now when you pan/zoom the map any pending queries are cancelled